# Action of noncentral mapping classes on curves or arcs on a surface

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, mapping-class-groups

$\DeclareMathOperator\MCG{MCG}$Let $\Sigma$ be a compact oriented surface, with empty or connected boundary. Let $\mathcal{O}$ the space of orbits of nontrivial simple closed curves on $\Sigma$ under $\MCG(\Sigma)$-action. (so, $\mathcal{O}$ has finitely many elements: the sets of nonseparating curves and the sets of separating curves of each possible genus)

If $f\in \MCG(\Sigma)$ is a noncentral element, is it true that for each $o\in \mathcal{O}$, there is a curve $c\in o$ such that the geometric intersection number $i(f(c),c)$ is non zero ?

Also, in the case where $\Sigma$ has one boundary component, I would like to ask the same question but for arcs (for the geometric intersection number, consider homotopy of arcs fixing the boundary and count only intersection points in the interior)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is true - there are many ways to prove it, but I'll hit it with a hammer. Let $C(\Sigma)$ denote the [curve complex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve_complex) of $\Sigma$. Suppose not, then $f$ would map every curve $[c]$ in $\mathcal{O}\subset C(\Sigma)$ to $[f(c)]$ which has distance $\leq 1$ from $[c]$ since $i(c,f(c))=0$. Since the neighborhood of radius 1 of $\mathcal{O}$ is equal to $C(\Sigma)$, we see that $f$ is [quasi-isometric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-isometry) to the identity acting on $C(\Sigma)$. Schleimer and Rafi [showed that $Aut(C(\Sigma))\cong QI(C(\Sigma))$](https://arxiv.org/abs/0710.3794), hence $f$ acts trivially on $C(\Sigma)$. Then by [Ivanov's theorem](http://www.math.stonybrook.edu/%7Emlyubich/Archive/Geometry/Hyperbolic%20Geometry/Ivanov.pdf) $f$ is the identity (or central if $\chi(\Sigma)\geq -2$).

Answer (score 3):

If there are infinitely many (isotopy classes of) curves, then yes. Here is sketch of a proof. Let $S$ be the surface and let $\mathcal{C}(S)$ be the curve complex. The diameter of the curve complex is infinite. The mapping class $f$ acts elliptically or hyperbolically on the curve complex, but in either case it has arbitrarily large orbits, so the curve you want exists.

Comment: This was the first approach I thought of, but it still seems like using the hyperbolicity of the curve complex is overkill, there ought to be a more direct argument.

Comment: Perhaps a lighter proof would "only" use the Nielsen-Thurston classification? However, there will be sticky bits where we have a partial pA map $f$ supported on a small subsurface (say a handle).  Then the curve may meet the support of $f$ in just an arc and there are a few cases to consider.  Hitting the problem with a hammer seems like the correct solution...

Comment: In the case of a surface of even genus and a curve separating it into sub surfaces of equal genus there is a direct proof. I feel like there ought to be a proof like this in general.